# Show that there is no point P = (x, y) with integer coordinates of the parabola

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Show that there is no point $P = (x, y)$ with integer coordinates of the parabola $y=\frac{1}{7}x^2-\frac{3}{7}$

It is part of number theory and congruences but I really do not know how to solve the above task? Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: since this is a question about integers and congruences, start by rewriting your equation as one with integer coefficients.

Comment: You should look at the values of $(n^2-3)\bmod 7$. Try a few.

Comment: Does this have anything related to diophantine equations? Im just asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $7$, you are asked to show that the equation $$7y=x^{2}-3$$ has no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}$. Assume by contradiction that $(x_{0},y_{0})\in\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ is a solution. Reducing the equation $7y_{0}=x_{0}^{2}-3$ modulo $7$ then gives $$x_{0}^{2}\equiv 3\ \text{mod}\ 7.$$
Hence $3$ would be a square modulo $7$, which is a contradiction. (Since $0,1,2$ and $4$ are the only squares modulo $7$).

Comment: I understand how you think and I can see that it is the solution to the problem. Can you explain that last step? "Hence 3 would be a square modulo 7, which is a contradiction (Since 0, 1, 2, and 4 are the only squares modulo 7) @studiosus

Comment: We got that the equation $x^{2}\equiv 3\ \text{mod}\ 7$ has a solution, namely $x_{0}$. Let's see why that is impossible. We calculate all possible values of $x^{2}\ \text{mod}\ 7$ and check that $3$ never occurs. We have $0^{2}\equiv\ 0\ \text{mod}\ 7$, $1^{2}\equiv\ 1\ \text{mod}\ 7$, $2^{2}\equiv\ 4\ \text{mod}\ 7$, $3^{2}\equiv\ 2\ \text{mod}\ 7$, $4^{2}\equiv\ 2\ \text{mod}\ 7$, $5^{2}\equiv\ 4\ \text{mod}\ 7$ and $6^{2}\equiv\ 1\ \text{mod}\ 7$. Indeed, $3$ does not occur as a square modulo $7$.